# apply mask/filter in a image flex mobile (ios)

Tags: flex-mobile

how can I add a mask/filter in some image ?!
It's like instagram filter ! (I have a image , then I choose a filter, then I put everything in a single image.)

Comment: I'm trying merge two imagem .. like here: [link](http://www.webdevotion.be/blog/2009/08/05/how-to-merge-two-images-into-one-in-actionscript/) but nothing happened !

Comment: That's a good start.  How did you integrate that code into your own?  Did you get an error?  What results were you expecting to see?  How did you expect to see them?  And why didn't you?